# How to preload upload gif when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page where I do the verification of the user and then redirect it. I need to add a standby gif to the screen as soon as the user clicks the log in button.  But the verification process takes some time until the result is returned from the service.  How can I cache and view the gif?

here is my css

```
.message {
            margin: 0px; 
            padding: 0px;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            background-color: #666666; 
            z-index: 10000;
            opacity: .8; 
            filter: alpha(opacity=70);
            display:none;
            background: url("assets/images/waiting.gif") no-repeat center center;
        }
```

here is my html code

```
<form id="signinForm">
            <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail"/>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
            <input id="login" type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
        
        <div id="divLoading" class="message">
            <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
            </p>
        </div>
```

here is my jquery code

```
<script> 
          $('#login').click(function (ev) {
                $("#divLoading").show();
                ev.preventDefault();                    
                setTimeout(()=>                    
                $.ajax((getUserInfoForSignIn())).then(r=>{
                    $("#divLoading").hide();
                }), 100);                                                   
               return false;
            });         
        </script>
```

My gif with the updated code comes up when I click the login button. The critical point here was that I called my user authentication function running on the web service inside my ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

-- use this on layout -

```
<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px;
top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001;
opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70);display:none">
<p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
    <img src="~/loading.gif" height="150" width="150">
</p>
```

-- then call by this way -

```
  $("#divLoading").show();
  $("#divLoading").hide();
```

Comment: inline styling is just for your reference , you still can change it as per your usage.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing as a working snippet:

```js
$('#signinForm').submit(function(ev) {
  $("#waiting").show()
  ev.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(()=>
    $.ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1").then(r=>{
      console.log(`${r.name} is now logged in: ${r.username==="Bret"}`);
      $("#waiting").hide();
    }), 2000);
  return false;
});
```

```css
#waiting {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="signinForm">
  <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
  <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
  <input id="login" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<img id="waiting" src="https://icons8.com/preloaders/preloaders/1485/Gear.gif">
```

Please note, that the gif is made visible immediately before the AJAX call and it is hidden again in the callback of the `$.ajax(...).then()`.

Comment: this is how it works. But $('#login').click(function () {}); instead of $('#submitForm').submit(function () {}); I guess I should use it. The form doesn't go to validation and the gif just keeps returning.

Comment: It works just as well with `$('#signinForm').submit()` - see my edited post.

Comment: I am doing user verification similar to yours on an ajax call as follows,
`setTimeout(()=>
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function (request) {
$("#divLoading").show();
},
complete: function (request, json) { $("#divLoading").hide(); }
}), 2000);`
This is causing the da gif to take longer to reload.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the updated code works exactly as I want.